# can't read json str in csv file with golang

Tags: csv, go

I export mysql data to a csv file, and there is one field use json string

when i use "encoding/csv" read this file, it show "wrong number of fields in line"

but when i delete the field, it's ok

like this:
[code example](https://play.golang.org/p/314zrsZG3R)

is anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You botched up quoting.
To quote a `"` in CSV your preceed it with one more double quote (and not with backlashes):

```
id,name
42,"Henry Walton ""Indiana"" Jones Jr."
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you ingesting is broken, you need to handle this manually. Catching error and putting record back in the format that you want.

https://play.golang.org/p/82bfDGLwFd

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    csvReader := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(data))
    csvReader.LazyQuotes = true
    csvReader.Comma = ','
    csvReader.Comment = '#'
    for {
        row, err := csvReader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {

            // checking here if the error you getting is what you experiencing 
            // due to json which is too many fields
            // checking for len(row) > 1 to avoid array index out of bound
            if e, ok := err.(*csv.ParseError); ok && e.Err == csv.ErrFieldCount && len(row) > 1 {
                // we manually stitch it back to the expected format
                row = []string{row[0], strings.Join(row[1:], "")}

            } else {
                // some other type of error
                fmt.Println(err)
                continue
            }
        }


        for _, str := range row {
            fmt.Print(str, "\t")
        }
        fmt.Print("\n")
    }
}

const data = `id,request_time
129,"{\"request\":{\"protocol\":\"http\",\"method\":\"POST\",\"is_ajax\":false,\"query\":{\"signature\":\"\",\"timestamp\":\"1511107236\",\"nonce\":\"\",\"openid\":\"\",\"encrypt_type\":\"aes\"},\"url\":\"\",\"origin\":\"\",\"host\":\"\"},\"response\":{\"status\":200}}"
`
```

Have fun!

Comment: it is work, but it change the string, perhaps, i should not use \,  this csv file generated by php

Comment: yeah that is correct if you are using backticks for string literal, you do not need to escape quotation marks ".